# How to configure log4j to enable/disable logging to a file?

Tags: java, log4j

I've written up a small console utility.  Throughout the application, I have used slf4j/log4j to log debug, trace, info statements to the console as I was developing it.  Now that I am done development and want to release it, I would like to disable all output to the console except for a couple of specific loggers and send all the remaining loggers to a text file.

In theory, this should be fairly easy.  I have created 2 appenders (one ConsoleAppender and one FileAppender).  I have assocaited the ConsoleAppender with the specific loggers want on the Console and the FileAppender at the Root level.  This works fine.

My issue now, is if I want to completely disable the FileAppender, I cannot figure out how to do it.  If I add a DenyAllFilter to the FileAppender, it will prevent anything from being written to the file, but the file is still created.  If I remove the FileAppender from the ROOT logger, I get Log4J writting to StdErr:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

If I set the ROOT level to OFF, the individual loggers that I have set custom debug levels to still output.

If I set the LoggerRepository Level to OFF, then all loggers (those I want to go to STDOUT and the File) are all shut off.

Is there any way to do this easily?  Ideally, I want to be able to disable the file appender altogether, however provide a command line switch to enable it if desired.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p %c{5} - %X{messageId} - %m%n" />
<!--            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%m%n" /> -->
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="LOGTXT" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="lss-client.log" />
        <param name="append" value="false" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p %c{5} - %X{messageId} - %m%n" />
        </layout>
<!--        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter"/> -->
    </appender>

    <!-- Spring Loggers -->
    <logger name="org.springframework">
        <level value="INFO" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing.sent">
        <level value="TRACE" />
    </logger>   

    <logger name="org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing.received">
        <level value="TRACE" />
    </logger>   

    <logger name="com.cws.cs.Client" >
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>

    <root>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="LOGTXT" /> 
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Thanks!

Eric

Comment: Can you post your configuration, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure Slf4J/Log4J creates the log file immediately when you configure a `FileAppender`.

I think your best bet here is to have 2 different and complete Log4J configurations and pick which one you load at startup based on your command line parameter.

In PseudoCode:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    //if log to file arg = true
        DOMConfigurator.configure("logToFile.log4j.xml");
    //else
        DOMConfigurator.configure("logToConsoleOnly.log4j.xml");
}
```

**Edit**

Furthermore, if you don't like the idea of maintaining two configuration files. You could create one configuration with the common components (probably the spring stuff and w/e else) and then based on your parameter, programatically configure the `FileAppender`:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    DOMConfigurator.configure("log4j.xml");
    //if log to file arg = true{
        // Define layout
        PatternLayout layout = new PatternLayout();
        layout.setConversionPattern("%d{ISO8601} %-5p %c{5} - %X{messageId} - %m%n");

        // Create appender
        FileAppender appender = new FileAppender();
        appender.setFile("lss-client.log");
        appender.setLayout(layout);
        appender.activateOptions();

        // Get root logger and add appender.
        log = Logger.getRootLogger();
        log.setLevel(Level.INFO);
        log.addAppender(appender);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was trying to come up with a solution like that, but I've been running into a problem.  If I add the fileAppender to the Root logger only programatically, then the Root logger has no appender by default and I get the log4j warning that it is not configured.  (I can probably get around that by creating a second console appender that had a deny filter on it, but that is an ugly solution).

Comment: You could initially configure Root Logger to use `NullAppender`. http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/varia/NullAppender.html

Comment: Is there a way I can access a configured Appender in my log4j.xml that may not have been associated to a logger yet?  That would alleviate my need to create/configure it programatically, but just to associate it instead.  Ex: something like Appender.findByName( "FILE_APPENDER"), but I cannot seem to find a method that would give me that access.  getRootLogger().getAllAppenders() will only return an Enumeration of appenders already associated to the rootLogger.

Comment: To my knowledge that is not possible. And like I said initially, I'm pretty sure Log4J creates the log file as soon as the `FileAppender` is configured. So if you don't even want the log file there, I think you're best option is to configure the `FileAppender` at startup.

Comment: Good point.  I've been going through the DOMConfigurator code in the meantime, and indeed, it does not look like it is possible.  The appenders only seem to be parsed upon use so if there are no loggers that use the appenders, they are simply ignored.  And I can confirm that the file is created as soon as the appender is parsed, even before any logging occurs.